# Kotlin companion null when called from Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, singleton

I have a singleton class in kotlin using the companion keyword.

```
    class POIsEngine private constructor() {

    private object Holder {
        val INSTANCE = POIsEngine()
    }

    companion object {
        val instance: POIsEngine by lazy { Holder.INSTANCE }
    }
}
```

When I call it from a Java class

```
POIsEngine.Companion.getInstance()
```

throws a null pointer exception.

I have noticed that this method gets called twice on the load of the fragment, the first time it is null, the second time it is initialized.

Could it be the case that the companion class is not being initialized fast enough?

Edit: Added Holder

Comment: Whats `Holder.INSTANCE ` here ? add it with question

Comment: This is kind of off the topic. But if you need a singleton, you might better consider using Kotlin object instead of class declaration: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: An obvious reason is `Holder.INSTANCE` is null . If you want to use Singleton in kotlin you can go with `Object` . Or if u r lust playing around add the code for Holder with question so that someone can answer.

Comment: I don't have the freedom to change around this code as it is deep into the project and it's implemented the same way on more than 100 classes. But this is the only case that we call it from Java code